# Creating a Multiline Environment

Tags: formatting

How do I go about making a multiline environment similar to that done with `\begin{center}` together with `\end{center}`? For example, how could I create such an environment that adds the symbol `[` at the start and `]` at the end using the commands `\begin{bracket}` and `\end{bracket}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\newenvironment{bracket}{%
[%
}{%
]%
}%
\begin{document}
  \begin{bracket}
     Foo, bar.
    \end{bracket}
\end{document}
```

[image]